# python postgresql insert error while adding SEQUENCE for auto increment

Tags: python, postgresql, insert, syntax-error, sequence

Below is mainly everything that is dependent

```
authorname="samuel"
bugid=1222
filename="mila.txt"
conn = None;
cursor = None;
conn = pg8000.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="root", host="localhost")
cursor = conn.cursor()

def createTables():
    cursor.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE FILE_id_seq")
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE FileTable(ID INT UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('FILE_id_seq'), filename varchar(250) NOT null UNIQUE )")
    cursor.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE Author_id_seq")

    conn.commit()
    return

def insert_filename(filename1):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO FileTable (filename) VALUES (%s)', (filename1))
    conn.commit()
    return

insert_filename(filename)
```

I am getting an error while inserting

```
ps = cache['ps'][key]

KeyError: ((705, 705, 705, 705, 705), 'INSERT INTO FileTable (filename) VALUES (%s)')

g8000.ProgrammingError: (b'ERROR', b'42P18', b'could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

Note : With Serial datatype i have the same error. I have updated the code

Comment: What is the value of `filename1`? It looks like it may be the *tuple* `(705, 705, 705, 705, 705)` from the error text...

Comment: OK, so not clear where the `(705, 705, 705, 705, 705)` is coming in... what does the line that calls `insert_filename` look like?

Comment: filename="tkk.txt"
insert_filename(filename)

Comment: actually when i am inserting into both columns, its working but i want my first column which is ID to be auto incremented. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm...still not seeing where the 705 tuple comes in... where does the `cache` dict stuff come into play in terms of `insert_filename`? Seems like perhaps some code is missing from the post that may be key to the behavior you're seeing, since a sequence will generally auto-increment under the `DEFAULT` specification when not specified...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure where the `(705, 705, 705, 705, 705)` tuple is coming from... the `cache`-related code is not in the main body of code...

However, a couple of things...

1. `createTables` is never called.
2. `(filename1)` is not a valid argument to `execute`. That's not a *tuple*. For single-item *tuple*s, you need to add a trailing comma, i.e. `(filename1,)`.

When I added a call to `createTables` and changed the argument to have a trailing comma, the auto-increment works fine for me using your `insert_filename` code.